# How to return array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, return

Why does the following code not work?

It compiles fine but output is something like an address if I write `f` using `*` and the output is `0` if I write `f` without `*`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
using std::size_t;
int *f(size_t s){
    int *ret=new int[s];
     for (size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
          ret[a]=a;
      return ret;
      }
int main(){

    size_t s=20;
    cout<<*f(s)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should it be doing?

Comment: You have already asked a dozen questions here and still don't know how to format code? What keeps you from heading the hints beside the edit box?

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working? From what I can see, it should be working just fine.

Comment: ...and, of course the code you posted has a heap memory leak (since you never `delete[]`) , but I suspect that is the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 12):

You're using C++, simply use std::vector instead, it simplifies everything :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> f(size_t s){
    std::vector<int> ret( s );
     for (std::size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
          ret[a]=a;
      return ret;
      }
int main(){

    std::size_t s = 20;
    std::vector<int> v = f(s);
    for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) // go through each element
        std::cout<< *it << std::endl;

    for( int idx = 0; idx != v.size(); ++idx ) // simpler variant that is equivalent in this example
        std::cout<< v[idx] << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This misses a few `std::` prefixes. Nevertheless, `+1` from me. This is the only sane option for newbies.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to fix this after copy-pasting the code from the question...should be fixed now.

Comment: +1 from me as well, however, many times it is a requirement of a homework assignment to not touch standard containers - speaking from experience.

Comment: I didn't assume it was a homework, only thought the asker was searching a way to return "arrays" from functions.

Answer (score 11):

The function `f(s)` returns the address of the dynamically allocated array.

If you do 
`cout<<f(s)<<endl;` it will print that address and if you do `cout<<*f(s)<<endl;` it prints the value at index `0` which is `0`.

If you want to print the entire array, run a loop as:

```
int *p = f(s);
for (size_t a=0;a<s;a++) {
    cout<<*(p+a)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

f(s) returns an int* so *f(s) is an int (the 1st item of the allocated array) with the value of 0. That's what it should appear, just a 0

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to understand it when the code is separated into 2 lines:

```
int* ret = f(s);
cout<<*ret<<endl;
```

*ret == ret[0] == 0. Because of that it prints 0 for the code you posted.

***Note** that you are allocating an array (using new) but never deallocating it.

If your intention is to print all the elements in the array, you can use the following code:

```
size_t s=20; 
int* ret = f(s);
for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
    cout<< ret[i] << " ";
delete[] ret;
```

Comment: `delete ret` is invoking undefined behavior, it should be `delete[] ret`.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As @frag says, main() knows nothing about the type of `f(s)` except that it is a pointer to `int`.  It doesn't have any reason to look for 19 other ints.

Your main function should look more like this:

```
int main(){

    size_t s=20;
    int *p = f(s);
    for (size_t i=0; i<s; i++)
      cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get an array out of a function is by giving a reference to it as an input argument (i.e. pass in a pointer to the start of the array), then once your function is complete, the array you passed in will have been populated by the function. I wouldn't advise even trying to return one.

An alternative is something like the STL Vector (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) class or similar variants, which can be returned, but it really depends on what you intend to use it for.

Comment: That's a dynamically allocated array. The code should work fine the way it is.

Comment: I was always taught it was bad practice to return an array created in a function. That just seems a bit messy.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now. OK, yeah, upvoting codaddict.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `<<` operator to output an array. You have to create a `for` loop and print each entry.

Save the output of `f` to a variable and print each entry.